# php. Echo don't work in infinity loop after readline

Tags: php, echo, readline

I'm trying write simple script which will work from console, but I ran into a problem. Echo in my case does not work. But when I delete the line: readline ('Command:'), it starts working as expected, so I tried to replace echo with print_r, but that did not help. I launch a script from the Windows console.

```
<?php
while (true){
    $input = readline('Command: ');
    $input = strtolower($input);
    echo $input;                    //don't work
    switch ($input){
        case 'stop':
            exit(0);
            break;
        case '1':
            echo 1;                //don't work
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Command ' . $input . ' not found.';  //don't work
    }
}
```

Comment: By not working you mean?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: ^... `readline` is not available under windows by the way, I just tried your code in Ubuntu and it's working fine.

Comment: @NigelRen I tried to run the script from the Windows console.

Comment: @MehdiBounya That seems to be an old information! I was just running his program on Windows 7 with PHP 7.1.9. It work's perfectly!?

Comment: @MaxSenft I just checked the note, it was written 6 years ago so maybe it is included now.

Comment: @MaxSenft Call to undefined function readline() for me on windows 10 with PHP 7.0.20

Comment: @SashaS. can you explain what do you mean by "It's not working"??

Comment: @MickaelB. See also the bug report at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74489 stating _"As of PHP 7.1, the readline extension is compiled into PHP for Windows. [...]"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the user comments on the documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php#104181 ...

> The readline library is not available on Windows.
>
> ```
> if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT') {
>   echo '$ ';
>   $line = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1024, PHP_EOL);
> } else {
>   $line = readline('$ ');
> }
> ```

So try

```
  echo 'Command: ';
  $input = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1024, PHP_EOL);
```

As has been pointed out, as of PHP 7.1, this function is available on Windows, but prior to that it looks as though you can do the above.

Comment: That seems to be an old information! I was just running his program on Windows 7 with PHP 7.1.9. It work's perfectly!?

Comment: See also the bug report at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74489 stating _"As of PHP 7.1, the readline extension is compiled into PHP for Windows. [...]"_

Comment: Thanks! It helps.

Comment: @MaxSenft  So if OP is running anything less than PHP 7.1 then it may not be included?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, just edit your answer to explain that and it is good to go.

Comment: @MehdiBounya thank you too, I understood what was my mistake.